# How to make in Linear layout half Frame Layout and half Grid Layout?

Tags: android

I am trying to accomplish in xml to show half frame layout and half grid layout without specifying it by myself with `dp`  Here is what i want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="#FFFF00"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </FrameLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/buttom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="3" >
    </GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I don't want to specify size of this:

```
android:layout_height="250dp"
```

As i would then need to recreate this xml for all sizes. Maybe i could change something and android will calculate for all sizes ?

Thanks.

Comment: you should probably use `android:layout_weight`

Comment: Give the grid and the frame the same layout weight.

Comment: Yes this isn't java question. Sorry for that, instinct worked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify weight property as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#FFFF00"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

    </FrameLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/buttom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:numColumns="3" 
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

by adding `layout_weight="1"` in both framelayout & gridview